# Angular Material Datepicker - How to specify a certain date as valid outside of daterange

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

In my code, I set minDate to a specified date, and then maxDate can either be null or a specified date. I need for the datepicker to always accept "12/31/9999" which currently is only accepted when maxDate is set to null.

If I have min and max Dates set to a certain range, how do I still have the datepicker allow "12/31/9999" as an acceptable date?

This is Angular material datepicker.

```
group.form.controls["date"].setValue(new Date());
(question as DateTimePickerQuestion).minDate = new Date(this.policy.effectiveDate);
if (question.controlType == "datetimepicker" && (value == "CP" || value == "NR")) {
    (question as DateTimePickerQuestion).maxDate = null;
} else {
    (question as DateTimePickerQuestion).maxDate = new Date();
}
```

This is the html generated by our code.

```
<input _ngcontent-aaj-c321="" matinput="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c78-84 cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" 
    ng-reflect-name="date" ng-reflect-placeholder="Date" ng-reflect-min="Sat Sep 12 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0" 
    ng-reflect-mat-datepicker="[object Object]" id="mat-input-22" placeholder="Date" aria-invalid="false" 
    aria-required="false" aria-haspopup="dialog" min="2020-09-12">
```

I am currently trying to do this.

```
 newComment.form.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
  this.update();
  this.CheckDate(newComment.form);
});

private CheckDate(form: FormGroup) {
     if (form.controls["date"].value == new Date("12/31/9999")) {
         form.controls["date"].valid = true;
     }
}
```

But this doesn't work because valid is a readonly property. How do I force a control to be valid?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do the validation of the field by hand since if you set the maximum date as new Date () the year 9999 will always be greater.

For that I would choose to capture the value change event in the formControl and establish manual validation at this point.

```
group.form.controls["date"].valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy)).subscribe(() => {
    //maximum and minimum validation logic
    if (error){
        /*
         * I do not know exactly the name of the error, I assume it is maxDate, 
         * for this you will have to establish the max min conditions in your current
         * code, set a date out of range and debug the errors property of formcontrol
         * object to see the
         * exact name and thus be able to use the message already implemented by the 
         * component
         */
        group.form.controls["date"].setErrors({ "maxDate": true });
    }else{
        group.form.controls["date"].setErrors(null);
    }
    
});
```

Comment: Hello, I'll paste what I'm attempting to do right now as it is is similar.